# GenerationType.TABLE : Big numbers in the data base

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an interface named Log and two subclasses `DescriptiveLog` and `TraceabilityLog`
So i want to create table for each subclass. 
My interface is like :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

public abstract class Log implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
    private Date date;
    private String actor;
    ...
}
```

and my sublclasses :

```
@Entity
public class DescriptiveLog extends Log {
    private String description;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class TraceabilityLog extends Log {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="traceabilityLog")
    private Collection<TraceabilityLogItem> traceabilityLogItems;
}
```

An the DataBase i have an other table named `hibernate_sequence` whit one attribute Log
When i save an Traceability or descriptive Log i see in the Data base a values like 24535 in the ID of them
So i want to separate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you need to give the JPA provider (hibernate in your case) more information if you want to use the table strategy to generate ids for your table.

Assuming that your `hibernate_sequence` table has `seq_name` to hold the primary column names and `seq_val` for holding the next available id then your mapping should be something along the lines:

```
@TableGenerator(name = "LogGen", table = "hibernate_sequence",
                pkColumnName = "seq_name", valueColumnName = "seq_val", allocationSize = 1)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "LogGen")
private Long id;
```

If you have just created the log tables then you can set the `seq_val` for the log table to 1.

Comment: When i add that in my class a new error :
the inspection controls whether the persistence orm annotations are checked against configured Datasource

Comment: Ok but that is a IDE error.. do you have actual problems during runtime?

Comment: Thank you, No problems during runtime.